# click on the texture area

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I'd like to create a function that will be called by clicking on texture object. I've just figured out how the button action is processed. Could you tell me plz how it works. Maybe some special controls have to be correspond to texture object?
thanks in advance )))

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is for iOS and by click you mean tap. The following code will add a gesture recognizer to any `UIView`:

```
    myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

    [myView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

And implement your handler like this:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {     
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

The `handleTap:` method will be called every time your view receives a tap.

Comment: Thank you ))) But I'm difficulty, my glkView is a rectangle all of my screen and that's why this method is called from any tap area of screen rectangle. How can I link a texture object to UIView ??? I have a  function of button processing and it doesn't work because of all screen defines like a view recognizer

Comment: Do this to your recognizer: `recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;`. This will make your button work.

Comment: And if you want to receive tap on your image, add the recognizer to your `UIImageView` containing your image instead of main view.

Comment: I don't understand (((( I did same thing and it doesn't work. self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];  
    UIImageView * im1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.image];
    [view addSubview:im1];      and then I add recognizer like that :    [im1 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer]

Comment: Try this: `im1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`