# setting up UITapGestureRecognizer in XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm working on an app in which I want the user to be able to tap an image and trigger another method (already written and tested; it works), but I've gotten very confused about what I need to do to make this work.  I've used the XIB to set up the UIImageView (and I know I need to drag a UITapGestureRecognizer onto the UIImageView, and I know I need to allocate and initiate it with target and action in viewDidLoad), but I don't know what to connect to what in the XIB after that, or what properties/methods to write.  (The state of the UITapGesture recognizer is irrelevant--it should do the same thing whether it's UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan or UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.)

What are my next steps?

As usual, thanks very much ahead of time.

Comment: I always do it [from code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162819/click-on-the-texture-area/12163044#12163044).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm personally a fan of setting these up with code, so here's an example of that. First of all in your header file you will want to create an `IBOutlet` for the `UIImageView` and then link the outlet to your image view in interface builder.

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` (or where ever you want really) you can set up the recognizer and add it to the image view.

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure you enable user interaction on the image view or this won't work!

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];    
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myMethodToCall)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to make the image the background of a button and use connect the the IBOutlet for "touch up". Here's one of many, many tutorials out there on how to connect outlets. http://www.servin.com/iphone/iPhone-Buttons.html